Scalar functions under diffeomorphism of domain
Consider the space of functions $F(\mathbb{R^n}) := \{f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R^n})| \lim_{|x|\to \infty} f(x)=0 \}$. Consider the space of coordinate transformations on the domain $\mathbb{R^n}$, which I will denote as $Diff(\mathbb{R^n})$. Intuitively I would expect that two functions $f_1 \in F(\mathbb{R^n})$ and $f_2 \in F(\mathbb{R^n})$ are connected under such a coordinate transformation if and only if they have the same number of maxima, same number of minima, and same number of saddles, with the $f$ values of the critical points being equal between $f_1$ and $f_2$.
Assuming that this is correct, consider the following scenario: the space of functions $G(\mathbb{R^n} \times \mathbb{R^n}) := \{f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R^n}),  $ such that $ f(x,x)=0, f(x,y) = f(y,x)$ where $x,y\in \mathbb{R^n}$ and $ \lim_{|x|\to \infty} f(x)=0 \}$. Consider the space of coordinate transformations $Diff(\mathbb{R^n})\times Diff(\mathbb{R^n})$ - and I emphasize not $Diff(\mathbb{R^n}\times \mathbb{R^n})$ . Would it be possible to check if two functions $f_1 \in G(\mathbb{R^n} \times \mathbb{R^n})$ and $f_2 \in G(\mathbb{R^n} \times \mathbb{R^n})$ are related by such a coordinate transformation by comparing critical points, like in the simpler scenario of the previous paragraph?
EDIT, allow degenerate coordinate transformations, such that $\det\Big|\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}\Big|=0$ for at most countably many points in $\mathbb{R^n}$.

Hint: Prove that your intuition is wrong already for $n=1$.

What counterexample do you suggest?

Hint: Consider the functions
$$
f_1(x)=e^{-x^2}
$$
and
$$
f_2(x)=e^{-x^4}.
$$
Prove (by studying the critical point $x=0$) that there is no diffeomorphism $g: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ such that $f_1=f_2\circ g$.

I have edited my question to accommodate the case of degenerate coordinate transformations.

@Joeseph123: It is not hard to modify my example to account for the change in your question. I am leaving it to you to figure out the modification.
